# JBoss Fuse and Orchestration

Tags: web-services, jbossfuse, fuseesb, orchestration

we have a JBoss Fuse server on which we are going to deploy  a number of SOAP /REST web services.
Some of these services need to call other web services within the ESB server itself.
I was thinking about doing this using Orchestration.
Does anyone know if JBOss Fuse supports that ? As far as I know JBoss Fuse supports CXF web Services but not sure if it does support Orchestration.

Any ideas on any solutions to implement that would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. JBoss Fuse uses "Gateways" for that. You deploy the http-gateway profile for instance, and it will act as a loadbalancer and proxy for all instances of a particular http resource across the cluster.

See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/html/Fabric_Guide/Gateway.html

Comment: Thanks for the info but I was asking for Orchestration support rather than load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your services in JBoss Fuse as OSGI services. This will allow to call them inside the same container in which these services deployed. If OSGI services need to call from the outside, it is possible to wrap them in CXF service. Also, fabric8 gateway allows you to virtualize services location, services in the same container will be called via a local optimized transport, remote services will called through CXF web services.